# Unable to run Python script from CMD using shortcut but able to using full path

Tags: python-3.x, batch-file

I have just started learning programming and following a certain book but encountered the following error. Not sure where I went wrong.

I have a python script named pw.py in the folder C:\Users\myname\MyScripts, and I've included the header
"#! python3".
I also have a batch file named pw.bat in the same folder with the following code:

```
@py.exe "C:\Users\myname\MyScripts\pw.py" %*
@pause
```

I have added "C:\Users\myname\MyScripts" into the Environment Variables (both with and without "\" after MyScripts. Not sure if it makes a difference though but both didn't work).

When I tried to run at Win+R using 'py "C:\Users\myname\MyScripts\pw.py" cmd', the python script runs properly.

However when I tried 'py pw.py cmd', it doesn't work. 'py "C:\Users\myname\MyScripts\pw.bat" cmd' doesn't work either.

My command prompt opens at 'C:\Users\myname>'. Not sure if this is the problem? If so, how should I change my codes?

What have I missed?

Thanks.

Comment: If you open the command prompt and run `where py`, what does it return? It's not the location of your scripts that you need to add to your path, it's the location of `py.exe`.

Comment: Also, please remove ```C:\Users\myname\MyScripts``` and ```C:\Users\myname\MyScripts\``` from wherever/whichever environment variables you saw fit to mess about with.

Comment: The title of your question specifically mentions a shortcut. Where in your question body does that shortcut get mentioned? Are you trying to run ```pw.py cmd``` or ```py "C:\Users\myname\MyScripts\pw.bat" cmd``` somewhere within your shortcut properties? If so, where? and how?

Comment: 1) "where py" leads me to "C:\Windows\py.exe" and I do have an env var of "%SystemRoot% in the System variables.

Comment: I am trying to run "py pw.py cmd" in at WIN+R. As mentioned in the book. (I've just realized it mentioned for the pw.bat into the C:\WIndows folder, which I just did but it still doesn't work.)

Comment: assoc .py shows ".py=Python.File"; ftype Python.File shows: Python.File="C:\WINDOWS\py.exe" "%L" %*

Answer (score 0):

Realized my mistake. At Win+R, should use

> pw cmd

instead of

> py pw.py cmd

Thank you all!